# Using two WHERE conditions when extracting data from a Nested SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently stuck with a relatively straight-forward SQL query.

Working_schedule table is

```
Work_ID   Work_grade   Work_shift       Work_Process    pay_grade
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1         senior       day              manual          1
2         mid          day              auto            5
3         mid          day              auto            2
4         junior       night            manual          1
```

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Work_shift)
FROM Working_schedule 
WHERE Work_shift = 'night'
  AND Work_grade = 'senior'
(SELECT Work_id
FROM Working_schedule ws
INNER JOIN Area_branch ab
  ON ab.Area_Branch_ID = ws.FK_Area_Branch_ID
INNER JOIN regional_branch rb
  ON rb.regional_branch_id = ab.FK_regional_branch_id
INNER JOIN Country c
  ON.c.country_location = rb.FK_country_location
WHERE c.Company_origin = 'Spain')
```

I have to count how many night workers, who are also seniors work companies of Spanish origin.

Currently I am able to filter for all night workers who are seniors, but I am unsure of how to check to see if they work for companies of Spanish origin.

I can also get filter for all companies of Spanish origin and (through a series of inner joins) find out the `work_ids` in the `Working` schedule table.

My question is how do I connect the two queries (or even can I)? If not, how should I resolve this problem? I have attempted this with INTERSECT, UNION and UNION ALL but nothing has worked.

The output anticipated is a number - number of `work_shifts` at night that are also `work_grade` senior.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's usually helpful to include a sample of the output you need when asking for help with queries. You've shown some input; please add output.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have corrected Inner Join and amended the tags to SQL-Server. The output should be a number (number of work_shifts at night that are also work_grade senior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(ws.Work_shift)
FROM Working_schedule ws
     INNER JOIN Area_branch ab ON ab.Area_Branch_ID = ws.FK_Area_Branch_ID
     INNER JOIN regional_branch rb ON rb.regional_branch_id = ab.FK_regional_branch_id
     INNER JOIN Country c ON.c.country_location = rb.FK_country_location
                            AND c.Company_origin = 'Spain'
WHERE ws.Work_shift = 'night'
      AND ws.Work_grade = 'senior';
```

This method uses an inner join to filter out all data except for that where the company_origin = 'Spain'

Comment: Yep, and from a performance point it's generally faster than a nested IN statement

Answer (score 1):

A small tweak in your query should be enough.

`SELECT count(ws.Work_id)
FROM Working_schedule ws
INNERJOIN Area_branch ab
  ON ab.Area_Branch_ID = ws.FK_Area_Branch_ID
INNERJOIN regional_branch rb
  ON rb.regional_branch_id = ab.FK_regional_branch_id
INNERJOIN Country c
  ON.c.country_location = rb.FK_country_location
WHERE c.Company_origin = 'Spain' and ws.work_shift='night' and ws.work_grade='senior'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Work_shift)
FROM Working_schedule 
WHERE Work_shift = 'night'
AND Work_grade = 'senior'
AND Work_id in 
(SELECT Work_id
FROM Working_schedule ws
INNER JOIN Area_branch ab
  ON ab.Area_Branch_ID = ws.FK_Area_Branch_ID
INNER JOIN regional_branch rb
  ON rb.regional_branch_id = ab.FK_regional_branch_id
INNER JOIN Country c
  ON.c.country_location = rb.FK_country_location
WHERE c.Company_origin = 'Spain')
```

Comment: dean, why wouldn't you unroll the inner query

Comment: Hogan, what would the query look like if you unroll the inner query?

Comment: @Hogan, that is an option too.

Comment: @Notaclue -- like any of the other answers that don't have a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the operator you are looking for is IN:

```
SELECT COUNT(Work_shift)  
FROM Working_schedule   
WHERE Work_shift = 'night'  
AND Work_grade = 'senior'  
AND Work_id in 
(SELECT Work_id  
FROM Working_schedule ws  
INNERJOIN Area_branch ab  
  ON ab.Area_Branch_ID = ws.FK_Area_Branch_ID  
INNERJOIN regional_branch rb  
  ON rb.regional_branch_id = ab.FK_regional_branch_id  
INNERJOIN Country c  
  ON.c.country_location = rb.FK_country_location  
WHERE c.Company_origin = 'Spain')
```

Comment: Ahh too slow... I knew I shouldn't have checked if IN also works in SQL server, since I just worked with Oracle ;)